# Getting Script Error from ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox

This problem keeps occuring. Any function within the ArcToolbox gives this error message with different code. The message below comes from using the 'Hillshade' tool.

I've updated my ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2 to SP5 and i've tried changing the security settings in Internet Explorer (V. 11.0.9600.17633) but no positive result.

The ''regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\msxml3.dll'' solution doesnt work.
Reinstalling ArcGIS doesn't work either.

also tried these solutions:

https://gisnuts.com/terra/blog/2013/01/22/arcgis-geoprocessing-tools-scripting-error, http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38099, http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33792

no avail

[image]

Comment: Update internet explorer and hope for the best. Yes, that's right, even if you use Chrome or Firefox you need to update Internet Explorer.

Comment: yes, i've tried the usual changeS in settings and updateS. Current version of IE is 11.0.9600.17633.

Comment: What about Javascript? is that updated too? Have you checked that the file c:\users\jan-willem\appdata\roaming\esri\desktop 10.2\arctoolbox\dlg\mddlgcontent.htm exists and can be accessed? Line 57 (for me) is Window_onresize(); in function InitForm. I Arc will recreate it if it's renamed, try renaming the file to MdDlgContent.htm_old then open a tool from the toolbox in catalog (any tool, it doesn't matter), that should recreate the file.

Comment: my current version of Javascript in IE11 is 1.8.0_31. I've done what you described above, it does create new .htm files but it doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: Then it's time to log a support request with Esri. Without actually being there I can't advise any further; you've done everything possible to resolve this yourself. If you don't have Esri support then you may have to uninstall/reinstall the whole computer... a good excuse to buy a new one!

Comment: So i contact ESRI, who redirected my to my university. The solutions given by the university are the same as i can find here. I'm just going to go with QGIS i guess. Seriously ESRI, how can one small error cause the whole program to disfunction.... thanks for all the input and help

Comment: Been there, done that. In one case we had to start with a fresh system disc, install windows.... Quite a pain! The excuse was something 3rd party was installed that interfered with whatever Esri was trying to do. If possible move to another workstation.